# actionIcon.items is not defined in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

To display menu items below code is written. It throws actionIcon.items not defined error

```
private mergeMenusIcons(actionMenus: ActionMenus[], overrides: ActionMenus[]): ActionMenus[] {
    const mergedIcon = [ ...actionMenus ];
    overrides.forEach(override => {
      const { scope, menus } = override;
      const found = mergedIcon.find(m => m.scope === scope);
      if (found) {
        menus.forEach(menu => {
          const actionIcon = found.menus.find(a => a.actionName === menu.actionName);
          if (actionIcon) {
            actionIcon.items.push(...menu.items);
          } else {
            found.menus.push(menu);
          }
        });
      } else {
        mergedIcon.push(override);
      }
    });
    return mergedIcon;
  }
```

Comment: You can just do this: `actionIcon.items = [...menu.items];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the items array before you add items,

```
if (actionIcon) {
  actionIcon.items =[];
  actionIcon.items.push(...menu.items);
}
```